# http.request does not care about options parameter when url is of type Request and not string in Angular

Tags: angular

I noticed that when calling `http.request`

```
request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>
```

the `options?: RequestOptionsArgs` parameter seems to be ignored if the `url: string|Request` parameter is of type Request and not string. If it is type Request then this overrides any headers set on the optional options parameter.

Angular version: 2.4.2

Can anyone confirm this? Is this intended behaviour or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be correct,

```
 request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let responseObservable: any;
    if (typeof url === 'string') {
      responseObservable = httpRequest(
          this._backend,
          new Request(mergeOptions(this._defaultOptions, options, RequestMethod.Get, <string>url)));
    } else if (url instanceof Request) {
      responseObservable = httpRequest(this._backend, url);
    } else {
      throw new Error('First argument must be a url string or Request instance.');
    }
    return responseObservable;
  }
```

Source code: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/http.ts#L113